# using SFINAE to change function called in a class depending on type of class template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I have a templated class that can take either a scalar, or an indexed type, and I would like to call a different version of a function depending on what type it is:

```
template <typename Ta, typename ... T>
struct MyClass {
    Ta tt; //can be either a scalar (double, complex<double>, int, etc), 
          //or an indexed type (MyClass, std::vector<double>, double[], etc)

    //....

    //I would like the following to be called when tt is a scalar type:
    auto operator[]( size_t i ) { return tt; };

    //I would like the following to be called when tt has [] overloaded:
    auto operator[]( size_t i ) { return tt[i]; };

};
```

Is there a way to do this?  Return value SFINAE doesn't work (because there isn't a template parameter on this function), Class based SFINAE doesn't seem to work (because the variadic template makes having a dummy template parameter at the end not work).  Any other ideas?

Comment: Note that "auto" for a function return type is in C++1y standard. In C++11 you should use syntax like this: "auto operator[]( size_t i ) -> decltype(this->value(0, 0))" (as described above in the answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe Xeo misunderstood what Andrew meant by "scalar". Xeo is following the C/C++ definition of scalar (as per C++11, 3.9/9) and Andrew meant something closer to the linear algebra sense (an element of the underlying field of a vector space). For instance, while for Andrew `std::complex<double>` is scalar, this is not the case for Xeo since he uses `std::is_scalar<std::complex<double>>` to check that and, of course, he gets `false`.

I believe, what Andrew wants is `operator[](size_t i)` to return:

1. `tt[i]` if `tt[i]` is legal; or
2. `tt` if `tt[i]` is illegal.

We can easily SFINAE away the first candidate above. By implementing a trait that checks whether calling `tt[i]` is legal or not, we can also SFINAE away the second candidate when the expression is legal. Creating this trait isn't very straightforward and relies on overload resolution (reall the classic `no f(...)`). I'll skip the creation of the trait and, instead, use the same ideas directly inside `MyClass`. To avoid polluting `operator[]()`'s signature with a dummy argument (needed for the overload resolution trick) I'll create private methods called `value()` which take the dummy argument. Then `operator[]()` will just delegate the call to one of them.

The code follows.

```
#include <type_traits> // for std::declval

template <typename Ta>
class MyClass {

    // This overload is SFINAEd away when tt[i] is illegal
    template <typename T = Ta, typename R = decltype(std::declval<T>()[0])>
    R
    value(size_t i, int) { return tt[i]; }

    // This one is always present but is a worse match than the other
    // one when resolving value(i, 0).
    const Ta&
    value(size_t, ...) { return tt; }

public:

    Ta tt;

    auto operator[]( size_t i ) -> decltype(this->value(0, 0)) {
        return value(i, 0);
    }

};
```

Comment: A good point about what might be meant with "scalar", +1. I thought about going the "is `tt[i]` valid" route too, but I was too lazy to write what you have. :) Btw, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9154394/500104) may be of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks! this is indeed what I was interested in.

Answer (score 3):

Just give the `operator[]`s a dummy template parameter.

```
template<class U = Ta, EnableIf<std::is_scalar<U>>...>
auto operator[]( size_t i ){ return tt; };

template<class U = Ta, DisableIf<std::is_scalar<U>>...>
auto operator[]( size_t i ) { return tt[i]; };
```

See [here](http://rmartinho.github.com/cxx11/2012/06/01/almost-static-if.html) for some explanation about this particular style of SFINAE.